# Scala wrongly pointing a double definition

Tags: scala, generics

In Scala, I'm trying to define two functions of the following type

```
def to(sinks: Sink[RequestModel, NotUsed]*): VyasaGraph = {
  val current = sinks.toList
  connect(previous, current)
  previous = current
  this
}

def to(functions: Function1[RequestModel, Unit]*): VyasaGraph = {
  val current = (for (func <- functions) yield Sink.foreach[RequestModel](func)).toList
  connect(previous, current)
  previous = current
  this
}
```

Why is sbt producing a double definition error

Comment: Can you please post a [MCVE] of the problem? No one will be able to compile this example (unless they explicitly bring in Akka Streams).

Comment: Minimal example:

def to(x: Int*): Int = 1;
def to(f: String*): Int = 1

Answer (score 7):

So the reason why it is throwing a double definition error is because, varargs are passed as `Seq[T]`. Since generic types are erased at compile time, both the functions would be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You already found the reason, but the standard workaround is to add an always-available implicit parameter to one of the methods, and that's what `DummyImplicit` in `Predef` is for:

```
def to(functions: Function1[RequestModel, Unit]*)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = ...
```

If you need to distinguish more than two functions, you can have multiple `DummyImplicit` parameters or define your own extra types:

```
class DummyImplicit2
object DummyImplicit2 {
  implicit def d: DummyImplicit2 = null // to avoid creating garbage
}
...
```

Comment: def to[_ : ClassTag](functions: Function1[RequestModel, Unit]*) should work too. Unsure if there is some impact on bytecode in this case.

Comment: `DummyImplicit` exists in `Predef` for this specific reason, so using it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks, great to know. The only reason was to avoid defining my own.

Comment: Or just avoid overloading in the first place and give more specific names to these methods instead of `def to(...)`.

Comment: We ended up defining our methods with a first mandatory parameter and the rest of the parameter as varargs. This suites our needs as we always need the user to pass on atleast one argument